# Why can't we figure out how neural networks produce results?

Tags: machine-learning

If we know what input features go into a model and we know what features or aspects of features each neuron is responsible for, why are deep neural networks "black boxes?" It's not clear to me why we can't just print out the weights and biases assigned to each neuron and see how they change as the model's accuracy improves.

The explanations I've heard have all been versions of "it's just a lot of numbers." I can see how it might be difficult to keep track of all of the neurons in a complex neural network, but why is it impossible? (And is it possible in smaller models?)

Comment: “*It's not clear to me why we can't just print out the weights and biases*” This [question on ai.se](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22673/what-exactly-are-the-parameters-in-gpt-3s-175-billion-parameters-and-how-are) mentions 175 billion parameters, they could be printed but it would be useless. And it may require several centuries just to print these values.

Comment: Good question.  We can figure it out, but it's not simple or easy. Staring at billions or trillions of numbers isn't very helpful, so we produce 3D graphs to figure it out all the time.

Comment: should this not go on the AI site?